# How to add data from one column to two created columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my Column named "Total Board Quantit" to have all its data go to two created columns named "Total Pallets" and "Total Boards".

Total Boards will have all values from Total Board Quantit that are greater than 28.01.
Total Pallets will have all values lower than or equal to 28.
There's also data in Total Board Quantit that are lower than 1 that I do not want to show which should be on the macro already.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DATA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet     'Dim, dimension. Declare variable to be used later

    On Error Resume Next    'Continues executing statement, ignores error
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Set to false to suppres prompts
    Sheets("DATA").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0         'Disables any error trapping currently present in the procedure
 
    Dim fName As Variant, wb As Workbook 'Variant data type can be used to define variables that contain any type of data
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Disable events to avoid workbooks_open to be started
    
    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*") 'fname, file with excel file ext
    
    On Error Resume Next    'Continues executing statement, ignores error
    If fName = False Then   'False, exit, msg will show
        MsgBox ("No SAP Data selected!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    wb.Sheets(1).Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2) 'Importing data from first sheet on to this wb, second location
    ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA" 'Naming the sheet DATA
    wb.Close False            'Close workbook
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    '''
    Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
    Dim rngHeaders As Range

    Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
    Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="Total Pallet Quantit", After:=Cells(1, 1))

    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Total Pallets"
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Total Boards"
  
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$247").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">1", _
      Operator:=xlAnd
        
    '''
    
    Dim arrIn, arrOut As Variant
    
    lastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    arrIn = rngUsernameHeader.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lastRow, 1).Value
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 2)

    For x = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        num = arrIn(x, 1)
        If num <= 28 Then
            arrOut(x, 2) = num
        ElseIf num >= 28.01 Then
            arrOut(x, 1) = num
        End If
    Next x
    rngUsernameHeader.Offset(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, 2).Value = arrOut
    
End Sub
```

What I'm getting
[image: Image of what I'm getting on excel]

Comment: Hey, just ran the code on a quick mock up and it works gind, except for this line ` ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$247").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">1", Operator:=xlAnd` which was maybe just because my mock up was simplistic, not sure what it's trying to do though?  also just noticed you have  `On Error Resume Next` set for this piece of code.  be careful setting this when you are working up code, it knocks out the standard error pop up which can be extremely useful at pinpointing the issue

Answer (score 1):

So you have inserted the two columns and now want to populate them with data.

I think here arrays are your friend:

*Edited for comment by @TimWilliams, thanks!*

```
Sub arrayTransfer()
    Dim arrIn, arrOut As Variant
    
    lastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    arrIn = Range("A2:A" & Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 2)

    For x = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        num = arrIn(x, 1)
        If num <= 28 Then
            arrOut(x, 2) = num
        ElseIf num > 28.01 Then
            arrOut(x, 1) = num
        End If
    Next x
    
    Range("b2:c" & lastRow).Value = arrOut
End Sub
```

update lines 4 and 6 to reference the column the data is actually in and the last line to the columns the data is going into

note if a value is 28.01 or negative it will not be in either column as per the questions.

let me know how you get on

Comment: fair - it was late and I couldn't remember the code!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. The data is in "DATA" while the columns I want it to go are "Pallets" and "Boards". Appreciate your help!

Comment: i think if you change `arrIn = Range("A2:A" & Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value` to `arrIn = rngUsernameHeader.offset(1,0).resize(lastRow,1).value`  and then change `Range("b2:c" & lastRow).Value = arrOut` to `rngUsernameHeader.offset(1,1).resize(lastRow,2).value = arrOut` i think that will work but honestly try see what it does and let me know how you get on.  are your two columns together and (pallets and boards) and whiich way around are they i.e. boards first is how this code runs so may assuming they are in adjacent columns

Comment: Ok went ahead and made the changes. Yes the columns are right next to each other. I changed it to Pallets and then Boards. Pallets less than or equal to 28 and Boards equal or greater than 28.01. Thanks for the help. I edit the main post with an image of what I'm getting.

Comment: so is that all good now?  if so could you just make as answered so people know there is a solution, if not let me know what's left

Comment: Oh sorry! No it did not fix it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOUlm.png .

Comment: i'm amazed that code even ran to be honest i didnt change it right earlier.  i have updated my edit if you copy and update the for loop that will update your code and try that

Comment: This is now what I'm getting. It works sometimes when I update the data on certain ones it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMSkl.png Every DATA sheet has the same names for the headers. Still not reflecting the data from the Total Pallet Quantit

Comment: ok I think you probably need to run this on just one sheet and probably run it step wise [ if you step through the code ([link](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/8020/debugger-locals-window) or more detailed ([link](https://madschedules.com/microsoft-project-vba-locals-window/))]  in the locals window you can expand out the arrays and see at each step what is happening to them.  not sure I can just see the issue, may be some one else can.  or looking through the code running step by step should show you

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that. Thanks a bunch!